# Why Sharepoint refresh it self after a javascript function was executed?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I've created a Button in a Content Editor, which changes for example the background color of the content box.

After i press the button, the background color is changed from black to white. But Sharepoint refresh it self automatically and didnt save the change. Does anyone have an idea about this ? It happens in IE and Chrome as well.

Best Regards,

Andy

```
<button onclick="changeCo()">Change Color</button> 
  <style>
    #contentBox {
    background-Color:black;
    }
    </style><script>
    function changeCo(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("contentBox");
        var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
        if (theCSSprop == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
        document.getElementById('contentBox').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        }else{
        document.getElementById('contentBox').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: When does the refresh happen? Remember that SharePoint is a server-based application and client-side code is just that, client-side. For changes on the client to persist between page refreshes, you need to store the changes and re-apply them. You can do that with cookies, but `localStorage` is easier.

Comment: The background-color changed and the site refresh itself. I forgot to put return false; after the button :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `type='button'` to your button element. This should prevent the page reload.

```
<button type='button' onclick="changeCo()">Change Color</button>
```

But One more thing as `@Scott Marcus` suggested, if you want to persist the changes even after page refresh/reload then you will have to store these changes to the server/cookies/localStorage.