# REST POST in sharepoint not posting data

Tags: jquery, rest, post, sharepoint

I did manage to get GET REST Share point working but I struggle with POST.

I have this code:

```php
function send_idea() {  
    //Fetch the values from the input elements  
    var idea_title = document.getElementById("idea_title").value;
    var idea_description = document.getElementById("idea_description").value;
    var listName = "Production_Request_Idea";

    $.ajax({  
        method: "POST",
        url: "URLTOSITE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Production_Request_Idea')/items", //name of the LIST
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            Title: idea_title,  //I did try to put Title in "Title" but still not posting
            Description: idea_description 
        },
        headers: {  
            accept: "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            swal("Item created successfully", "success"); // Used sweet alert for success message  
        },  
        error: function(error) {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }  
    })  
}
```

html:

```
  <abc runat="server" data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-once="true" method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="sendIdea">
     <label for="title">Title</label>
     <input type="text" id="idea_title" name="title">
     <label for="idea_description" >Description</label>
     <textarea id="idea_description" name="description"></textarea>
     <p>benefits:</p>
     <div class="benefits_container" >
        <div class="benefit" >
           <input id="quality_container" type="checkbox" name="quality">
           <svg class="benefit_icon svgColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
      some vector graphic
           </svg>
           <p>quality</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefit" >
           <input id="savings_container" type="checkbox" name="savings">
           <svg class="benefit_icon svgColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1">
              some vector graphic
           </svg>
           <p>savings</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefit" id="compliance_container">
           <input id="compliance_container" type="checkbox" name="compliance">
           <svg class="benefit_icon svgColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1">
              some vector graphic
           </svg>
           <p>compliance</p>
        </div>
     </div>         
     <button type="submit" onclick="send_idea()">send</button>
  </abc>
```

It does go to headers then it refreshes itself without going further so I assume there is an error which cause browser to refresh the site.

I have been trying since yesterday to figure this out but to no avail.

I did find only 2 examples on Stack and did not help me.

EDIT: I change form tag to something random just as test but now when submit is binded to button and not form it at least gets to a point of sending me error message which is 2130575251 - no rights even though I have full control..

Comment: This link might help you -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50256800/why-sharepoint-refresh-it-self-after-a-javascript-function-was-executed/50268533#50268533

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple things I noticed as to why the request won't work. When performing a POST request, the data needs to be sent as JSON and it should include a metadata object that specifies the type. Also, the request digest header needs to be included.

If you still experience the page refresh, please add the rest of your code.

```
function send_idea() {  
    //Fetch the values from the input elements  
    var idea_title = $("#idea_title").val();
    var idea_description = $("#idea_description").val();
    var listName = "Production_Request_Idea";

    //Include the metadata object and type
    var data = {
        "__metadata": {
            type: "SP.Data.Production_x005f_Request_x005f_IdeaListItem"
        },
        Title: idea_title,
        Description: idea_description
    };

    $.ajax({  
        method: "POST",
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Production_Request_Idea')/items", //name of the LIST
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {  
            accept: "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", //Sends as JSON
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() //Include request digest value
        },  
        success: function(data) {  
            swal("Item created successfully", "success"); // Used sweet alert for success message  
        },  
        error: function(error) {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }  
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, so what is ineresting is taht if I use:

url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Production_Request_Idea')/items",

then the website refresh itself right after this line without doing anything. Do you think there is a connection why a standard code does not work for me? I did notice this before and that is why I used whole url which was fine and the code continued after the line

Comment: btw even with the whole url I never get any console log or success message. The page just refreshed itself. I have no idea how to debug this..

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code, including the HTML? My guess is that you may be listening for a click event on a <button> element, and it is triggering the refresh since SharePoint page content is wrapped in a <form> element. If this is the issue, you would need to add the type attribute with value 'button' <button type='button'>.

Comment: You are right. Now I have the action binded to a button action but of coarse I have a different problem " System.UnauthorizedAccessException" even though I have full control for myself. Anyway I guess that is a different issue I'll try to google it. But god damn this is taking so long. I should have been a gardener. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: No problem. Could you post the full error message? Have you added the "X-RequestDigest" header to your request?

Answer (score 0):

Here i have modified some lines.Please try below with **PATCH method**.

This one is a working code for me.

***Please get back to me for any issue.***

```js
function send_idea() {  
     
    var idea_title = document.getElementById("idea_title").value;
    var idea_description = document.getElementById("idea_description").value;
    var listName = "Production_Request_Idea";
    var item = {
                 "__metadata": { "type": idea_title},
                 "Value": idea_description
     };
    $.ajax({  
        method: "PATCH",
        url: "URLTOSITE/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Production_Request_Idea')/items",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(item),
        headers: {
                                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                                "If-Match": "*"
        }, 
        success: function(data) {  
            swal("Item created successfully", "success");  
        },  
        error: function(error) {  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        }  
    })  
}
```

Comment: Hi, the same issue. It does not do anything and page just refreshed itself without any log or whatnot. Anyway that metadata look wrong. I think type cannot be some value of element rather something that can be found through API if I am not mistaken. This is what I found "SP.Data.Production_x005f_Request_x005f_IdeaListItem"